# nodejs dirty check if key exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dirty

I'm a newbie to Node.js. I am using Dirty to save data into a .db file, and I have no idea to check if the key I inserted through db.set() already exists.

In other words: I want to check if the key exists, and if it does, do something.

Comment: You want to check if the file exists before you start using a module? Why can't you just do what every programming language does and check if the file exists using the file apis? Are you just unable to find the node.js documentation? Seems like this page is where you want to start. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, what i mean is, that I want to check the key I have added to the database through db.set() if it exist.

Comment: Ah, thanks, because that absolutely changes the entire meaning to the question.

Comment: If you have already inserted it, then by definition it exists. If you want to check _before_ you insert it, it is not apparent why you can't just [`dirty.get(key)`](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty#dirtygetkey)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the basic documentation provided on: https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty

I would say the best way to handle this is to:

```
if(!!db.get(key)){
   //your value already exists
}
```

This system appears to be designed for the naive approach, and this is certainly the naive approach.

Comment: Don't forget that if the value stored for the key is "falsey" then this simple boolean test will miss it!

Comment: I would assume that OP would be storing values of substance and not need records in the set of `"",0,false` but that's just me.

Comment: Why not just `if (db.get(key)) { }`? If the check evaluates to false or null then the key doesn't exist.

Comment: meh ... same number of characters, mine indicates that you want a boolean value out.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a key exists by using [`dirty.get(key)`](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty#dirtygetkey) and checking if the returned value is defined (in case it is a "falsey" value such as false, zero, the empty string, etc.):

```javascript
var myKey='...', myVal=dirty.get(myKey);
if (typeof(myVal) !== 'undefined') {
  // Do something...
}
```

**[Original Answer Below]**

You can check if a file exists by using the [`fs.exists(...)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) function in node.js:

```javascript
fs.exists(myDatabaseFilename, function(exists) {
  if (exists) { /* Do something... */ }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the incredibly non-understandable question I asked! I have updated it.